# Migrations Failing - "No superclass method 'version' for #<ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, rails-activerecord, database-migration

**The Problem**

I am attempting to update a production database with a series of migrations without losing its current data. In starting from scratch, I've had no problems running all of the migrations on an empty database, or working forward with my development and test databases. However, in trying to run the migrations on a backup of our production database I am receiving a strange error, which in turn prevents all migrations from running.

**The Error Message:**

This is the result of running `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `version' for #<ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration >
C:in `map'
C:in `map'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

**The Error Message - Expanded:**

This is the result of running `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace`

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `version' for #<ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration >
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:53:in `version'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:844:in `block in get_all_versions'
C:in `map'
C:in `map'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:844:in `get_all_versions'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `migrated'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:990:in `ran?'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:967:in `block in runnable'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:967:in `reject'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:967:in `runnable'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

**Additional Info:**

- Database: sqlserver
- Ruby: 1.9.3
- Rails: 4.2.0
- Environment: Windows 7

**Actions Taken:**

A cursory check of my database proves that the schema_migrations table exists, and that it does contain a "version" column. Everything appears to be in proper order. For good measure I've tried dropping and (re-)restoring the database backup multiple times, deleting and regenerating the schema.rb, and running all of my migrations again from scratch. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this to fail.

**Research:**

I can only find one example of someone experiencing a similar problem ([here](https://gist.github.com/sam452/604f57c0525cf3416129)), and no clear resolution.

**I Need to Know:**

- What's causing this
- How to fix it
- OR an alternative way to update my database without losing its records

Comment: Stupid question, but you are looking at the database which is specified in the production block of your "config/database.yml" file, right?

Comment: Yes. In fact I can run a `rake db:schema:reset RAILS_ENV=production` and see the expected results in my production (backup), but that's not a solution for obvious reasons.

Comment: Hmm.  What i normally do in puzzling situations like this is go to the files/lines at the top of the stack trace and start putting lots of logging in.  Sorry that's rather vague.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue today. Turns out it was because in my `database.yml` I had other schemas in my `search_path`, and those schemas had tables named `schema_migrations` without the field `version`.

So if you're having this issue, make sure that there are no tables with the name `schema_migrations` except for the one you need in the search path.